# Paid every two weeks but health insurance premium is listed as monthly

Tags: health-insurance, paycheck

My husband gets paid every 2 weeks. I would like to know do they divide his health insurance payment between the 2 checks. It says per month on his paper work.

Comment: The title says he gets a paycheque twice a month but the body of your message says every two weeks. These are two very different situations. Also, what did HR say when you asked them?

Comment: Typically, the employer divides the annual cost by the number of checks.  If he is paid every two weeks, 1/26 of the annual premium (approximately) should be deducted each check.  If he is paid twice a month, it'll be 1/24 of the annual premium.

Comment: I've seen cases where 1/24 of the annual premium (or 1/2 of the monthly premium) is deducted every two weeks, except when there is a third paycheck in a month, in which case no insurance is deducted for that third paycheck. So it depends completely on the company's payroll policy. It should be a very easy question for them to answer.

Comment: thanks for all the help, and I am sorry I didn't word my question  right. He gets paid every 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the premiums will be divided. As mentioned in the comments, there are only 2 scenarios that make sense for employees that are paid biweekly:

1. The amount deducted from the first 2 paychecks each month is exactly half of the monthly premium. In months with a 3rd paycheck there is no premium taken out.
2. The amount deducted from every paycheck is exactly: (Monthly Premium * 12) / 26

If you have a paycheck (or stub) handy, you should be able to see which method they are using. If it's not one of those two then I'd recommend calling HR to find out how they calculate it (and then let us know because it is probably an abnormal calculation).